# How are the documents ordered in Elasticsearch if the sort value for two documents is same?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I was working with products data, here: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vLvMcFAFII6566SuksazDsHaYkz4XPsG/view?usp=sharing)

The search query that sort by keyword field tags using max mode is as follows.

```
GET product/_doc/_search
{
  "size":100,"from":20,"_source":["tags", "name"],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {"tags":{
      "order":"desc",
      "mode":"max"
    }}
  ]
}
```

Some documents have same sort value. I had read somewhere that if the sort value is same, it arranges by internal doc id (_id). However, the case does not seem so. See screenshot below:

[image]

First **_id: 961** followed by **_id:972** (fine). However, then came **_id: 114**. I am not understanding how it got random.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already seen, its random. To overcome this you can add another field to be used to sort when the sorting value for first field is same. As you want to use `_id` the query will be then as follows:

```
{
  "size": 100,
  "from": 20,
  "_source": [
    "tags",
    "name"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "tags": {
        "order": "desc",
        "mode": "max"
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```